# Substituting Dark LME with Amber LME in a Stout

Tags: extract, stout, extract-brewing, lme, substitution

I'm following [this stout](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=96969) recipe for the second time (it's a good one). I had planned to double the recipe to make ~ 40ltrs instead of 20ltrs.

The recipe calls for:

```
(2.7KG)  6 lb. Dark Liquid Malt Extract
```

My supplies just arrived and my homebrew store substituted 3 x 1.5 Kg Cans of Dark LME with Amber LME.

So I needed 5.5Kg of [Dark LME](http://www.johnsonsgarden.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/1/3/1304_2.jpg) in the first place, I now have 1 x 1.5Kg Dark LME and 3 x 1.5Kg [Amber](http://store.capncorkhomebrew.com/images/product/e/extract-liquid-extract-muntons-plain-amber-malt-extract-1-ti-256px-256px.jpg).

Does anybody know what the effect might be on my stout if I use the amber instead of dark? Would it turn out mostly the same except for colour? Just trying to figure out if I should kick up a fuss with my supplier.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kick up a fuss you'd be justified as it is not what you ordered.

But, I'd just throw in some extra Dark Patent Malt and Roasted Barley, may be an extra .5lb of each to try and pull back the colour. Adding extra Roasted barley may lead to a more harsh bitterness, but adding more patent black should be OK.

If you do nothing you should end up with a similar body, just will lack the darkness.

I would just go with what I'd got and see how it comes out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might just try follow the recipe as best I can with the amber, its a shame because the recipe is really good. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to turn out the same.  It will taste like a dark Amber, but it might not be roasty enough to taste like a stout.

When working with extract recipes its best to use plain lightly colored extracts and then use specialty malts to drive the beer into the style you are looking for.

Its a fairly dated recipe.  I suspect since its posting more people have moved on to just using lighter extracts with specialty grains for more control and fresher taste.